# Can a Facebook page message a user without the user first sending a message to the page?

Tags: facebook

I'm wanting to set up an app for a page(or possibly group) where if a user comments on the page then the page will send the user a private message.  So far I'm finding this to be impossible, I'm trying to make the following call via postman:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me/messages
{
  "recipient": {
    "id": "{receipientId}"
  },
  "message": {
    "text": "hello, world!"
  }
}
```

The error message I'm getting back is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#551) This person isn't available right now.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 551,
        "error_subcode": 1545041,
        "fbtrace_id": "{fbtrace_id}"
    }
}
```

I've seen this functionality with another app and I can't seem to find the documentation anywhere that allows this type of behavior, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The recipient id is coming from a page scoped user id.

Comment: Where did you get receipientId from?

Comment: One of my test user accounts posted a comment on my page during a live video, and I got the following result from 
`
GET https://graph.facebook.com/{{VideoId}}/comments?filter=stream
{
    "data": [
        {
            "created_time": "2019-04-25T21:36:59+0000",
            "from": {
                "name": "Test User",
                "id": "***recipientId***"
            },
            "message": "first comment",
            "id": "id"
        }
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok through more reading I was able to find the answer.  Private replies are how to do this.

Send a post to this endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{CommentId}/private_replies

{
    "message": "Hello, world"
}
```

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/object/private_replies